# Preserving the Client IP Address in Sun Java System Web Server

Tags: java, security, client, webserver, ip

We are running Sun java System Web server 7.0 and Sun Java System App Server 9.1 (glassfish) in our environment.

We need to perform some access control check in the application based on the client's IP address. Currently the method request.getRemoteAddr() when called from the application returns the Webserver's IP address. The method 
request.getHeader("HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR") returns null.

Looks like the web server is changing the header before forwarding to the application server.

Is there a way to let the Sun Java webserver retain the original client IP address in the request?

Please let me know.

Thanks

Comment: Can someone throw some light on this issue?

Answer (score 1):

Try `request.getHeader("x-forwarded-for")`. I tested it for Squid.

You can see every parameters names by iterating through `request.getParameterNames()`.